Valid sigalgs and ciphers in HTTP Request
I was wondering if there is some specific combination of ciphers and sigalgs which are 100% valid and doesn't get flagged anywhere.
For example, first I've found these:
ciphers: 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256', sigalgs: 'ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256:rsa_pss_rsae_sha256:rsa_pkcs1_sha256',
then these:
ciphers: 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384', sigalgs: 'ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256:rsa_pss_rsae_sha256:rsa_pkcs1_sha256',
So, I'm sending request using TLS, net.connect socket and hpack. There are also my secureOptions:
secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_TICKET | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_NO_RENEGOTIATION | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_ALLOW_UNSAFE_LEGACY_RENEGOTIATION | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_TLSEXT_PADDING | crypto.constants.SSL_OP_ALL | crypto.constants.SSLcom
but now they are both flagged as suspicious. So, how could I find exactly valid combination that imitates google chrome 122 windows for example, or something like that?
I was searching for google but without success, also chat gpt didn't helped. I'm expecting that my ciphers and sigalgs won't be flagged as suspicious ones.

You could use SSLlabs to see what the settings are for a given browser:
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html
